# Add a config to all projects in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I have

```
lazy val p1 = Project(...).configs(IntegrationTest)

lazy val p2 = Project(...).configs(IntegrationTest)

// etc (quite a few subprojects)
```

I can share settings between projects by using e.g. `scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.11.7"` without need for repeating [`.settings(commonSettings)`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Multi-Project.html#Common+settings) for each project.

Is there an equivalent for configurations, so I don't need to repeat `.configs` each time either?

Comment: What have you tried thusfar? Can you perhaps post an example of your SBT setup (build.sbt/Build.scala)?

Comment: @irundaia See the edit.

Answer (score 1):

As sbt can just use scala expressions, You could try putting all projects in a List/Seq and calling foreach on them.

```
List(p1, p2).foreach(_.settings(commonSettings))
```

You could try getting list of projects from sbt by looking at

```
buildStructure.value.allProjects
```

and calling foreach on that, but not sure whether that would work.